# Entirely Cookieless WordPress?

Tags: cookies

It's possible to serve assets from a cookieless domain.

Now is it also possible to serve everything cookieless? Of course it's not possible for admins, but for anyone who's not logged in, in theory it should be possible to serve everything without cookies, which would have advantages in terms of both GDPR and speed.

If so, how to achieve this?

Comment: Users who aren't logged in and don't comment won't be served any cookies by WordPress. So just don't let regular users comment or register and you won't be serving cookies. If users are getting cookies then you likely have a plugin or script that's setting them.

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/article/cookies/